# VirtualBox networking (inception computing)

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtualization

I am new to world of networking and now I am trying to connect 3 PC`s together. I have windows 7 host that runs Ubuntu64-bit server guest, that runs ubuntu32 server guest.

Win7- Host Only network (192.168.130.1, 255.255.255.128) + NAT - Ubuntu64 (192.168.130.2)

Ubuntu64 - Bridged adapter (that host-only)+NAT - Ubuntu32 (192.168.130.3)

From Ubuntu32 and Ubuntu64 I can access almost everything, but Ubuntu32 doesn`t see 192.168.130.1 but can ping Win7 network address.

I use static addresses for host-only and bridged. NAT is dhcp.

My goal is to access Ubuntu32 (192.168.130.3) from Win7 Host. Hopefully picture will help. http://s10.postimg.org/ealkyljnd/net1.png

Thank you for advices.

P.S. admin changed my win7 IP

WIN7 - ipconfig /all

```
Konfigurace protokolu IP systému Windows

   Název hostitele . . . . . . . . . : SERVER-HP
   Primární přípona DNS. . . . . . . : 
   Typ uzlu  . . . . . . . . . . . . : hybridní
   Povoleno směrování IP . . . . . . : Ne
   WINS Proxy povoleno . . . . . . . : Ne

Adaptér sítě Ethernet Připojení k místní síti:

   Přípona DNS podle připojení . . . : 
   Popis . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM
   Fyzická Adresa. . . . . . . . . . : 8C-DC-D4-34-54-1B
   Protokol DHCP povolen . . . . . . : Ano
   Automatická konfigurace povolena  : Ano
   Místní IPv6 adresa v rámci propojení . . . : fe80::ecba:13ea:521b:1e2e%11(Preferované) 
   Adresa IPv4 . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.105(Preferované) 
   Maska podsítě . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Zapůjčeno . . . . . . . . . . . . : 28. července 2015 9:25:54
   Zápůjčka vyprší . . . . . . . . . : 3. září 2151 16:29:44
   Výchozí brána . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   Server DHCP . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   IAID DHCPv6  . . . . . . . . . .  : 244112596
   DUID klienta DHCPv6. . . . . . .  : 00-01-00-01-1C-DC-BA-EA-8C-DC-D4-34-54-1B
   Servery DNS . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   Rozhraní NetBios nad protokolem TCP/IP. . . . . . . . : Povoleno

Adaptér sítě Ethernet VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Přípona DNS podle připojení . . . : 
   Popis . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Fyzická Adresa. . . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-00
   Protokol DHCP povolen . . . . . . : Ne
   Automatická konfigurace povolena  : Ano
   Místní IPv6 adresa v rámci propojení . . . : fe80::20c2:3e5b:7f01:f28%17(Preferované) 
   Adresa IPv4 . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.130.1(Preferované) 
   Maska podsítě . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Výchozí brána . . . . . . . . . . : 
   IAID DHCPv6  . . . . . . . . . .  : 269090855
   DUID klienta DHCPv6. . . . . . .  : 00-01-00-01-1C-DC-BA-EA-8C-DC-D4-34-54-1B
   Servery DNS . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
   Rozhraní NetBios nad protokolem TCP/IP. . . . . . . . : Povoleno

Adaptér pro tunelové připojení isatap.{57571915-478F-4B7F-8B4D-686E8FEE8366}:

   Stav média  . . . . . . . . . . . : odpojeno
   Přípona DNS podle připojení . . . : 
   Popis . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Fyzická Adresa. . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   Protokol DHCP povolen . . . . . . : Ne
   Automatická konfigurace povolena  : Ano

Adaptér pro tunelové připojení isatap.{534C73AB-EE51-44E2-9BE7-9807CF34ECD3}:

   Stav média  . . . . . . . . . . . : odpojeno
   Přípona DNS podle připojení . . . : 
   Popis . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Fyzická Adresa. . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   Protokol DHCP povolen . . . . . . : Ne
   Automatická konfigurace povolena  : Ano
```

WIN7 - route print

```
===========================================================================
Seznam rozhraní
 11...8c dc d4 34 54 1b ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM
 17...0a 00 27 00 00 00 ......VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
===========================================================================

IPv4 Směrovací tabulka
===========================================================================
Aktivní směrování:
         Cíl v síti   Síťová maska            Brána        Rozhraní Metrika
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.105     20
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0       Propojené         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255       Propojené         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255       Propojené         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0       Propojené     192.168.1.105    276
    192.168.1.105  255.255.255.255       Propojené     192.168.1.105    276
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255       Propojené     192.168.1.105    276
    192.168.130.0    255.255.255.0       Propojené     192.168.130.1    266
    192.168.130.1  255.255.255.255       Propojené     192.168.130.1    266
  192.168.130.255  255.255.255.255       Propojené     192.168.130.1    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0       Propojené         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0       Propojené     192.168.130.1    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0       Propojené     192.168.1.105    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255       Propojené         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255       Propojené     192.168.130.1    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255       Propojené     192.168.1.105    276
===========================================================================
Trvalé trasy:
  Žádné

IPv6 Směrovací tabulka
===========================================================================
Aktivní směrování:
 Rozhraní Metrika Cíl v síti      Brána
  1    306 ::1/128                  Propojené
 17    266 fe80::/64                Propojené
 11    276 fe80::/64                Propojené
 17    266 fe80::20c2:3e5b:7f01:f28/128
                                    Propojené
 11    276 fe80::ecba:13ea:521b:1e2e/128
                                    Propojené
  1    306 ff00::/8                 Propojené
 17    266 ff00::/8                 Propojené
 11    276 ff00::/8                 Propojené
===========================================================================
Trvalé trasy:
  Žádné
```

U64 - ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:6e:dc:df  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe6e:dcdf/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:31 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:80 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3510 (3.5 KB)  TX bytes:9668 (9.6 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:50:9b:85  
          inet addr:192.168.130.2  Bcast:192.168.130.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe50:9b85/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:40 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:252 (252.0 B)  TX bytes:6071 (6.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ca:a0:40:2c:e4:80  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

U64 - route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
192.168.130.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

U32 - ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:de:9e:a9  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fede:9ea9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2776 (2.7 KB)  TX bytes:2934 (2.9 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:cc:f4:8b  
          inet addr:192.168.130.3  Bcast:192.168.130.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fecc:f48b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2208 (2.2 KB)  TX bytes:648 (648.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:888 (888.0 B)  TX bytes:888 (888.0 B)
```

U32 - route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.130.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

Comment: You mean the Ubuntu32 VM is guest to the Ubuntu64 VM? Why would you want to do that? Or is this part of your test? What is the normal IP-address of Win7? What does U64 "see" on 192.168.130.1?

Comment: so u got vm inside vm? whats your ping result from 32vm and 64vm and win7 to eachother?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu32 is guest of the Ubuntu64, that`s for independent enviroment (e.g. it could run in cloud). IP`s are shown in the image (Win7 has 192.168.1.5). U64 can access everything, problems are between Win7 and U32. I don`t understand what is meant by "What does U64 "see" on 192.168.130.1?"

Comment: U32 -> Win7 (192.168.1.5) ping OK; U32 -> Win7 (192.168.130.1) ping destination host unreachable ; Win7 -> U32 (192.168.130.3) ping result request timed out

Comment: Can you update your post with outputs of the following commands: `ipconfig /all` (Windows 7), `route print` (Windows 7), `ifconfig` (Ubuntu32 and Ubuntu64), `route -n` (Ubuntu32 and Ubuntu64)?

Comment: My question about what U64 can see - you say that U32 doesn't see 192.168.130.1, so I ask what U64 can see. And what do you mean by "see"? For a cloud configuration I would use another setup: computer@home, vmhost with U32, at work or elsewhere host with VM U64. Then you have a more realistic situation. Amazon AWS does not have vms hosted inside a vm. It has many big ugly hosts each with many guest vms and they are all on the same range: 10.a.b.c and they all can talk to eachother if allowed by security policy.

Comment: Well my task is to do it like this, I would prefer another, simplier solution. I mentioned before that U64 can "see" everything as you can see in that terrible picture